# How to concatenate an HTMLCollection with an array?

Tags: javascript

It may sounds like a silly question but

```
var arr1 = ['1', '2'];
var arr2 = ['3', '4'];
console.log(arr1.concat(arr2));
```

will output `["1", "2", "3", "4"]`

But

```
var arr1 = ['1', '2'];
console.log(
  arr1.concat(document.getElementsByTagName('h1'))
);
```

will output `["1", "2", HTMLCollection[2]]`

How do I concatenate the html collection with an array ?

Comment: What exactly is it you want? The value of the `h1`?

Comment: @Marwelln the element

Comment: your collection is an array like object, not an array.

Comment: It's is a DOM Object. Not an array.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to convert the `HTMLCollection` into an array. The best way of doing this in modern Javascript is [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from). This converts any array-like object (or other [iterable value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#Iterables)) into a real Javascript array.

```
arr1.concat(Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('h1')))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `push.apply`, like so:

```js
var arr1 = ['1', '2'];
arr1.push.apply(arr1, document.getElementsByTagName('h1'));
console.log(arr1);
```

```html
<h1>x</h1>
<h1>y</h1>
```

And in ES2015+ (aka ES6+), you can use `push` with spread notation:

```js
var arr1 = ['1', '2'];
arr1.push(...document.getElementsByTagName('h1'));
console.log(arr1);
```

```html
<h1>x</h1>
<h1>y</h1>
```

Note that in both cases, this is different from `concat` in that it avoids creating a new array (it just modifies the original one referenced by `arr1`). Whether that difference is a good thing (not creating unnecessary objects) or a bad thing (I wanted a new array!) depends on your use case. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use *Array.from*, however it's [fairly new](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Browser_compatibility) so may not be supported by all the browsers you need. Some alternatives, the last of which will be supported by all browsers in use:

1. Spread syntax, which is new, only supported by the most recent browsers and no version of IE
2. *Array.prototype.slice.call* to convert the NodeList to an array, but will fail in IE 8 where passing host objects to built–in methods as *this* fails
3. *Array.prototype.map.call* to convert to an array. Avoids the IE 8 issue as *map* will need to be polyfilled (but then you might as well use a polyfill for *Array.from* and be done with it)
4. Use *array.concat.apply* and pass the NodeList as an argument, no need for polyfills for old browsers

Runnable snippet below.

```js
var arr = [0,1];
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');

// Use spread syntax, pretty new though
var spread = arr.concat(...divs);
console.log('Spread\n' + spread.join('\n'));

// Convert to array using slice, then concat
var sliced = Array.prototype.slice.call(divs).concat(arr);
console.log('Sliced\n' + sliced.join('\n'));

// Convert to array using map, then concat
var mapped = Array.prototype.map.call(divs, function(div){return div}).concat(arr);
console.log('Mapped\n' + mapped.join('\n'));

// Call concat with apply directly using concat
var conned = arr.concat.apply(arr, divs);
console.log('Conned\n' + conned.join('\n'));
```

```html
<div>div1</div>
<div>div2</div>
```